# Using Javascript to connect input from a data-list to an SVG map and vice versa

Tags: javascript, svg

```
var wordStates = document.querySelectorAll("#county");
var svgStates = document.querySelectorAll("#svg-map > *");

function removeAllOn() {
    wordStates.forEach(function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("on");
    });
    svgStates.forEach(function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("on");
    });
}

function addOnFromList(el) {
    var stateCode = el.getAttribute("value");
    var svgState = document.querySelector("." + stateCode);
    el.classList.add("on");
    svgState.classList.add("on");
}

function addOnFromState(el) {
    var stateId = el.getAttribute("class");
    var wordState = document.querySelector("[value='" + stateId + "']");
    el.classList.add("on");
    wordState.classList.add("on");
}

wordStates.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
        addOnFromList(el);
    });
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
        removeAllOn();
    });

    el.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        removeAllOn();
        addOnFromList(el);
    });
});

svgStates.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
        addOnFromState(el);
    });
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
        removeAllOn();
    });

    el.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        removeAllOn();
        addOnFromState(el);
    });
});
```

I currently have an SVG map of a state at the county level. I also have an input that takes a value from a datalist. I am trying to "link" the two with Javascript and have the SVG map highlight a county when I select the county from the input.

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64797528/edit) and include your HTML and CSS.

Comment: heres my codepen: https://codepen.io/eric-quach/pen/mdEarbe

Comment: Please don't post links to external sites. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)